# Retain window position, primacy, panels, programs & audio when monitors turned on/off

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

[image: monitors]

This is my current setup.
3 is my main ultrawide monitor, connected by displayport to GPU. Always on.
1 is a secondary monitor, connected by DVI to GPU, sitting directly above 3. Currently always off, will be occasionally on in general.
2 is our living room TV, connected by HDMI to GPU. Occasionally on for me to use, occasionally on for unrelated use, mostly off.

I would like:

1. 3, the ultrawide monitor, to be monitor 1, displaying the boot info so I can choose OS in grub and boot to BIOS if required. As I understand it this is impossible because NVIDIA's deep firmware decides the order of importance for connected devices is DVI, HMDI, DP, and nothing can change that. LMK if this is wrong.
2. To be able to turn monitor 1 on and have its panel appear in place. Rather than having to go into panel settings, unhide panel 1 (which is for that monitor. Panel 0 is for monitor 3), then drag it into place. As I understand it, this is impossible.
3. To be able to turn monitors off, and have their position be saved, and resume when they're turned back on. Evidence from NVIDIA X-settings that this isn't the case when I disabled monitor1 (layout was the same in display settings):

[image: monitors2]

4. For monitor2 to not automatically be enabled when it's powered on, but for monitor1 to do so.
5. With some/all of the above sorted, to be able to switch between settings with a single click. I've previous accomplished something like this with shell scripts:

[image: monitors3]

... but I don't know if this will retain all of the above settings. Perhaps it doesn't need to if I'm manually forcing it? Example script below for all 3 connected.

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 880x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 3440x330 --rotate normal --output DP-0 --off --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --primary --mode 3440x1440 --pos 0x1050 --rotate normal --output DP-3 --off --output DP-4 --off --output DP-5 --off
```

6. Every time I switch video output settings, it switches the audio to the motherboard output, which I basically never ever want to use and is the bane of my existence:

[image: audio]

Can I prevent this?

7. Every time I switch configurations e.g. enable monitor1 (which isn't primary) all the open windows go there, including the "do you want to keep this config", meaning I have to move them all back. Presumably due to point 1.

Any suggestions for any of this much appreciated!

Edit: more examples: turned on the PC today and the layout had the panel starting from the centre & going right offscreen:

[image: panel mess]

When I click my shell script to only use the main monitor (3), this is the subsequent layout:

[image: layout]

(Although maybe that doesn't matter if they're all in the right place when others are plugged in)